What is the difference between Game Capture and Window Capture in OBS?
In OBS Studio, if I want to capture a windowed game I can use either a Game Capture with the mode set to "Capture specific window" or a Window Capture.
What is the difference between a Game Capture and a Window Capture? Is there a reason to use Game Capture over Window Capture?

Game Capture offers the best performance. You should use it over Window Capture if possible.
From the OBS Knowledge Base:
Game Capture

This source directly captures the DirectX or OpenGL game you are playing. Game Capture is the most efficient way you can add your games to OBS Studio and should always be tried first.

https://obsproject.com/kb/game-capture-source
Window Capture

Window Capture allows you to capture a specific window and its contents. The advantages to using this source over Display Capture is that only the selected window will be shown, even if there are other windows in front of it.

https://obsproject.com/kb/window-capture-sources

